# I can't access phpmyadmin even though apache server is running

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

so i installed xampp then installed microsoft sql server 2008 r2. then the apache server was no longer working because some app stole the port 80 (damn, why don't these app makers just use a different port? what's special with port 80?)

so i followed a tutorial that fixes this, it said i should rename the 80 into 81 (or any number), the apache server started but phpMyAdmin didn't. then I followed another, it says, rename 80 into 8080 and 443 into 4433. same result.

I found another, saying in the root folder, I should rename the phpMyAdmin into lower cases which i did, but still, the apache server is running but the phpMyAdmin doesn't.

Comment: port 80 are the default HTTP port, and 443 are the default HTTPS port that's what special about them... how are you accessing phpmyadmin? I mean what is the url you are typing in the browser? also what are the folders in the 'www' directory of your xampp?

Comment: i access it using localhost/phpmyadmin (it worked before i installed sql server)

i see no "www" folder on my xampp folder

Comment: sql server ? phpmyadmin is for MySQL only as I remember, try accessing your phpmyadmin panel using this url 'localhost:81/phpmyadmin', use the port you finally set for apache instead of 81

Comment: o it worked, the tutorial that i watched (which replaced 80 into 81) told that but i didnt see the ':' so i typed 'localhost81/phpmyadmin' instead of 'localhost:81/phpmyadmin' thanks. put it on the answer so i could declare it as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try accessing your phpmyadmin panel using this url `localhost:81/phpmyadmin`, use the port you finally set for apache instead of 81